# Calculate KCV using OpenSSL CLI

Tags: openssl, 3des

I have a 128bit double length 3DES key and am trying to verify its KCV using OpenSSL on the command line but am not sure how to put together the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "0000000000000000" | xxd -r -p | \
  openssl enc -des-ede -K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef | xxd -p -l 3
```

Where the key is specified to openssl by "-K 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef", and the length of the KCV in octets (2 hexadecimal digits per) is specified to the trailing xxd by "-l 3".